# Rewrite profile.php?user=username to profile/username

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've created a very basic php templating system that I'm using to display a page with this URL: /basedir/index.php?page=*home*

The *home* content is served by the script home.php.

With a rewrite rule in .htaccess, I want my url to look like this: /basedir/home.

The problem that I'm having is that I've got stuck when it comes to rewrite one more GET variable that I'm using to display a user's profile. For now the profile page url looks like this: /basedir/profile?user=username.

Now I want it to look like this: /basedir/profile/username.

So far, my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /basedir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) ?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have no idea if this is good or if i have to write a completely new .htaccess file.

Comment: Laravel has prewritten htaccess, it works pretty good. You can just use their htaccess file. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls

Comment: Also you can check this tool, http://htaccess.mwl.be/ will give you better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: thank you @anwerj, i took a look but i still can't get it...for now X_x

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, and my limited understanding, I would guess something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^?]*) ?page=profile&user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

.. insert it above your `RewriteRule ^([^?]*) ?page=$1 [L,QSA]`.

Comment: Ahhh, I don't really know what @emma means, `/basedir/profile?user=username` or `/basedir/profile.php?user=username` or `/basedir/?page=profile&user=username`. Maybe you should ask to write an working answer.

Comment: Thanks.. I didn't pay attention to the title. :p Also, I'm not 100% sure about the slash before profile.php, but I fiddle with details until it works.

Comment: Hey guys! :D Sorry for my incomprehensible question O_O. Basicly my templating system is so basic that it displays my pages like this `/base/index.php?page=whateverpage.php` and i'm using htaccess to make it a bit friendlier, so the result until now is `/base/whateverpage`. The point is that when i want to display a profile page this is the url before rewrites `/base/index.php?page=profile.php?user=emma` and i want it to look like this `/base/profile/emma`

Comment: Okay, only one more question: `/base/index.php?page=whateverpage.php` or `/base/index.php?page=whateverpage`? (because in your first post it says `/base/index.php?page=home`) You can add the .php in the code..

Comment: Without `.php`, good point, sorry :D so this is before rewrites `/base/index.php?page=profile?user=emma` and i want it to look like this `/base/profile/emma`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at http://htaccess.mwl.be/ your url `http://www.example.com/profile/username` is converted into `http://www.example.com/basedir/?page=profile/username`

Now what you need to do is put `index.php` in `basedir` where explode the `page` and retrieve username.

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$parts = explode('/', $page);


switch($parts[0]){
    case 'profile':
        if(isset($parts[1])){
             $username = $parts[1];
             return doWhatEverYouWantToDoWithUsername($username);
        }
        return handleJustProfilePage();

    default:
        return yourDefaultHandler();

}
```

This approach is called `routing` you can make way better with some external routing libraries.

Comment: thank you for this answer! but is there any way to get it done using htaccess ?